# Enable Swagger with Jersey 2.0 using beanConfig

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, jersey-2.0

In jersy 2 application, I have the following configuration to setup swagger.

```
@ApplicationPath("/*")
public class CreativeDeliveryServiceApplication extends ResourceConfig {
/**
 * Registers the resources for the application and binds implementations to
 * interfaces for dependency injection.
 */
  public CreativeDeliveryServiceApplication() {
    register(MultiPartFeature.class);
    .......


    register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
    register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);

    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
    beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[]{"http"});
    beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/api");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.my.resources");
    beanConfig.setScan(true);

    packages(true, "com.my.resources");
 }
}
```

I tried to locate swagger.json at localhost:8080/api/swagger.json, but I got 404 resource not found.

I assume I should follow localhost:8080/{ApplicationPath}/{basePath}/swagger.json
because my app path is @ApplicationPath("/*"), so I leave it out as 
localhost:8080/api/swagger.json

How can I trouble shot this?

Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```